# Defining new council variable in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a dataset with approx. 14.000 observations (with an ID number and GPS coordinates). I have a plugin in QGIS from the Danish "Kortforsyningen" which can show all 98 councils in Denmark and their borders. Can I make a new variable that indicates which council the observation occurred in?

I am totally new to QGIS.

---

It is a layer from the plugin (I think). I tried the vector but I can only choose the dataset I uploaded to qgis and not the layer from the plugin.

Comment: Do you really have a plugin, or a layer? If you have a vector layer you may use `join attributes by location`.

Comment: It is a layer from the plugin (I think). I tried the vector but I can only choose the dataset I uploaded to qgis and not the layer from the plugin.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You need to obtain the councils as vector data, for example as a shapefile or geopackage. Then add the observations as a "delimited text layer" (Ctrl+shift+t) and join attributes by location to join the councils to the observations.

Comment: HI, @MikkelMadsen Can you please post the screenshot of your situation. What you are calling a plugin may be a vector layer. If that is the case, the solution would be simple.